# Lightbox2 on simple html site (non WordPress) not working and I've tried almost everything

Tags: lightbox2

I can't seem to get the thumbnails I have placed on this page to open in the lightbox:

http://prussellartist.com/custom-leather-dog-collar-gallery2.htm

I tried changing the order and placement of these 2 elements:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/lightbox.css">
<script src="dist/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

At a glance is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the JavaScript errors ... It seems like you forgot the fourth step of the getting-started guide (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) - namely - to include jQuery.